# Was using Umbridge's fireplace to get to the Ministry of Magic an option?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

In Order of the Phoenix, there were multiple examples that show that Umbridge's fireplace was connected to the Floo Network.

Later on, we know the trio and some DA members wanted to get to the Ministry of Magic to try to rescue Sirius. The only option that came to mind was using Thestrals.

Was using Umbridge's fireplace also an option? If so, was it not considered only because it didn't come to mind?

Comment: Woops sorry looks like a duplicate of [Why didn't Harry and Co. travel to the Ministry in OotP by the floo network?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47749/why-didnt-harry-and-co-travel-to-the-ministry-in-ootp-by-the-floo-network)

Comment: You can mark this as dupe yourself as the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

### It's seems that they did not think of it.

After they get rid of Umbridge, Grawp, and the Centaurs, Harry and Hermione discuss what to do:

> “Smart plan,” he spat at Hermione, keen to release some of his fury. “Really smart plan. Where do we go from here?”
>
> “We need to get back up to the castle,” said Hermione faintly.

There is no mention of what they would do once back in the castle, but there is also no mention of trying Umbridge's fire.

When Ron, Neville, Ginny, and Luna join them, they discuss it again:

> “Yes,” said Harry, as his scar gave another painful prickle, “and I’m sure Sirius is still alive, but I can’t see how we’re going to get there to help him.”
>
> They all fell silent, looking rather scared. The problem facing them seemed insurmountable.
>
> “Well, we’ll have to fly, won’t we?” said Luna in the closest thing to a matter-of-fact voice Harry had ever heard her use.

They debate how they will be able to fly, and who should come, and then when Harry again says that they don't have a way to get there, Luna again says that they should fly:

> “Well, it doesn’t matter anyway,” said Harry frustratedly, “because we still don’t know how to get there —”
>
> “I thought we’d settled that?” said Luna maddeningly. “We’re flying!”

No one offered any suggestions other than flying, and then the Thestrals appeared so there was no need for further planning.

If someone had thought of using Umbridge's fire, presumably he/she would have mentioned it.

### If they *had* thought of it, it might not have been a good idea.

They had just escaped from Umbridge's office. The gang of Slytherins that had been guarding them there were probably still in the area, or had gone to report what had happened. At that point people also may have realized that Umbridge hadn't come back. Her office would possibly have been under intense scrutiny by that point, and waltzing into it, or even anywhere in the castle, would likely have simply gotten the group detained again. So even if someone had thought of using Umbridge's fire, the group might have simply chosen to use the Thestrals in order to avoid the chance of getting caught if they would return to the castle.

Comment: I also wonder whether they'd have been get hold of any Floo powder.  Presumably Umbridge would have a supply, but it might be hidden and/or magically protected.

Answer (score 0):

If they were to use the fireplace they would've been detected by Umbridge, who has spells to detect unwanted people getting into her office, as Harry is told when he gets caught:

> "You think," she whispered, bending Harry's neck back even further, so that he was looking up at the ceiling, "that after two Nifflers I was going to let one more foul, scavenging little creature enter my office without my knowledge? I had Stealth Sensoring Spells placed all around my doorway after the last one got in, you foolish boy."

I wouldn't be surprised if this incident caused her to put up more safeguards.

Comment: Umbridge was out of the picture at this point.